# Wanna add a number to the ASCII code of the characters or bit shift

Tags: c#, ascii

Ok so im taking a string input, converting it to char array and also saving its ASCII in an array.

```
Random r = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name : ");
        char[] name = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
        byte[] by = new byte [name.Length];
        int[] arr = new int[name.Length];
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("F:\\abc.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            fs.WriteByte((byte)name[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <name.Length ; i++)
        {
            by[i] =  ( ((byte )name[i]));

        }
        //for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        //{
        //   arr[i] = (byte by[i] (Convert.ToInt16);
        //}
        // fs.WriteByte(48); fs.WriteByte(8); fs.WriteByte(60); fs.WriteByte(80);
        fs.Flush();
        fs.Close();
```

Its saving the ASCII...Any way we can convert it to int and add a certain number in the values.
Im basically doing it for encryption and its a little part of it. 
and
also if the number that we add could be randomly generated... Can we use it onwards when decrypting the text?

Comment: I am removing the cryptography tag,  this has nothing to do with encryption or security.

Comment: i'll post you the whole program when its done ;)

Comment: There are classes within the .NET framework for the purposes of encryption. Use them. **Do not** roll your own unless you are already an expert on cryptography.

Comment: Using the classes wouldn't have been a problem. But its my project and it has a criteria. We have to build from scratch and we cant use pre defined classes.

Comment: If it's for a toy project or educational purposes, fine. But if this is actually for real encryption for a real project, you are making a mistake.

Comment: Totally a 1st year level educational project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this properly is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
short[] shorts = bytes.Select(b => (short)b).ToArray();
int[] finalBytes = new int[shorts.length];
int[] randomKey = new int[shorts.length];
int ndx = 0;
Random r = new Random();

foreach (short b in shorts)
{
    int rByte = r.Next(1, 5000);
    int singleByte = b + rByte;
    finalBytes[ndx] = singleByte;
    randomKey[ndx] = rByte;
    ndx++;
}

// finalBytes now holds your data. Do something with it!
// randomKey holds your hash data. To decode this, you'll
// need to subtract the value in randomKey[n] from finalBytes[n]
```

As everyone else has said though, it is strongly recommended this code NOT be used in any production code!

Comment: Thanks man. This helped.
Its just a small educational project. But still I'm curious why shouldn't it be used in any production code?

Comment: @OsamaMunir - Because a talented hacker can reverse engineer your code and thus can compromise your efforts to secure whatever data you'd be securing

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.  You do not really need to convert to a number on a language level - your piece of information is easier to operate on as a string, or array of bytes.

The following code replaces the output part of your existing code, and does the bitwise addition of the random number using the `Random` instance `r`.

```
byte[] randomNumber = new byte[name.Length];
r.NextBytes(randomNumber);
for (int i = 0; i <name.Length ; i++)
{
    fs.WriteByte((byte)name[i] ^ randomNumber[i]);
}
```

Assuming you intend to store `randomNumber` somewhere separately, you will be using the same bitwise operator `^` for "decryption" in the same way as it is used here for "encryption".

Answer (score 0):

With C# it's a bit trickier, because (according [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9h8tsay.aspx)) Char is a 16 Bit Unicode numerical value, not just ASCII, so You must be careful with Non-ASCII symbols and parsing files with weird encodings. In other hand, it can be easily converted to Unsigned Short Int, Int, Double and some other type.

Basically, simple typecast might do the trick:

```
char character;
int ascii_code = (int)character;
//some fency math and encoding with ascii_code goes here...
char encrypted_char = (char)ascii_code;
```

Not sure, if Visual Studio allows math directly with `char` type variables (C, C++ do).